# Primefaces Accordion Panel background color not working

Tags: css, primefaces

Here is my Accordion Panel tab

```
<p:accordionPanel class="abc" value="#{ac.ab.listAn}" var="avar">
    <p:tab titleStyle="color:#ff8000" title="#{avar.title}">
        <div style="white-space: pre-wrap; background-color:#ffffff">
            <h:outputText value= "#{avar.detail}"/></div>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Here is the CSS content

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content abc {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Because of the background color set to white in the div, the content does display with white background, but there is a thick border around it, which is actually the background color of the accordion panel.

The need is to change the accordion panel background completely to while. The class content doesn't seem to work. Please suggest.

[Image Included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qOhJ.jpg)

Comment: Update any Fiddle. So that it will be easy to work on it

Comment: add some image so that it would be easy to understand how it is coming.

Comment: Sorry haven't used Fiddle, Have included an Image as a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got a chance to further research on this and the following code did the trick

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    background: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

Nothing else is needed.